# SASS Inconsistent Indendation bug

Tags: debugging, compiler-errors, sass

When I compile my sass file from the terminal, I get this error-

> error code (Line 37: Inconsistent indentation: 2 spaces were used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 8 spaces.)

The weird part is, line 37 of my file doesn't have inconsistent indentation! In fact, even when I comment out that line or delete all the lines upto line 20, it still throws that error!
Why is this happening?!

The line in question is line 5 in the code pasted below. (height: 118px)

```
#outeredges{
    width: 100%;

    .outerleftskewed, .outerrightskewed{
        height: 118px;
        background-color: $title_bg_col;
        width: 50px;
        -webkit-transform: skew(0,20deg);
        position: absolute;
        top: 125px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: -999;
    }

    .outerleftskewed2, .outerrightskewed2{
        @extend .outerrightskewed;
        top: 767px;
    }

    .outerleftskewed3, .outerrightskewed3{
        @extend .outerrightskewed;
        top: 1529px;
    }
}
```

I just tried this code in an online SASS compiler and it works perfectly fine there. I cannot figure out why it's misbehaving on my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using SCSS syntax, not SASS syntax.  You must use the correct file extension (.scss vs .sass) for the style of Sass you are writing so that the compiler knows how to interpret it.